# Some Fn Keys not working after BIOS upgrade (ASUS X401U)

Tags: wireless, brightness, bios, function-keys

Before upgrading BIOS from version 204, all Fn Keys were working properly. After successful upgrade via EasyFlash to version 313 of my [ASUS X401U](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/X401U/HelpDesk_Download/) some Fn keys are not working anymore which are:

1. Fn + F2= Wi-Fi (Wi-Fi LED indicator stays ON after press it a few times not turning OFF or ON or not switched)
2. Fn + F5 and F6 = Brightness Down and Brightness Up (No get dimming or brighter and stay to maximum level)

Can anyone fix my problem?

Best regards

Comment: Is the module asus-nb-wmi loaded? Check: lsmod | grep asus Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One could comment on why Asus changes this behaviour in the firmware and suggesting to go back to 204. Well not quite:

> **BIOS 303**
>
> 1. Fix bug that system can't enter into sleep state on UBUNTU OS

Also:

> **BIOS 309**
>
> 1. Compatible with WinXP, Win7 and Win8

I guess that was meant to say *"Added support for Windows 8"*.

I remember using the kernel parameter `acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"` as a workaround for some time on my Lenovo T530. But as the [Arch Wiki suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/extra_keyboard_keys#Laptops) this may also cause other problems, but you should try it out.

You can temporarily add `acpi_osi="!Windows 2012"` to the end of the `linux` line in GRUB by selecting the entry at boot, editig it with <kbd>e</kbd> and booting with <kbd>F10</kbd>.

If that worked you can make the changes permanent by editing GRUB defaults in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, then `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`) and add the string to a line that looks similar to this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` (save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and close with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>). Then run `sudo update-grub`.

You should report this as a bug to Launchpad anyway (leave developers to decide if this is fixable or not).